# Call a pushbutton callback within another pushbutton callback

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am trying to pushbutton callback in an another pushbutton callback, but I am having problems:

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
C_N_Callback(hObject,eventdata, handles)

   RN_Callback(handles, [], []);
```

I tried this but gave this error:

> Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Inside `RN_Callback` at first step where it is doing `getappdata`.

I also tried this:

```
C_N_Callback(hObject,eventdata, handles)

   RN_Callback(hObject,eventdata, handles);
```

This did not give error but when i run the GUI it keeps doing the procedure in `RN_Callback` (i guess on refresh).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `RN_Callback` is using the reference to `hObject`. Just to remind you, `hObject` is the object on which the callback is being called. So in your case, it will be `C_N` , which will be passed to `RN_Callback` instead of `RN`.

In that case, the code will be wrong, because it expects a GUI object of one type, but gets another. For example:

```
function RN_Callback(hObject,eventdata, handles)
     set(hObject,'String','This is me!');
end    

function C_N_Callback(hObject,eventdata, handles)
     RN_Callback(hObject,eventdata, handles);
end
```

Clicking on on `RN` will change its string. But clicking on `C_N` will change `C_N`, instead of `RN` as you might have expected.